# How to update appsettings.json using yaml in which Key name contains colon

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

**Background -**

I have a appsettings.json which has the key like "api:connection". This key name contains colon. I have yaml pipeline job which deploys the code to multiple environment - DEV, UAT, PROD with related appsettings.json values.

**Issue -**

I'm using variable in my yaml pipeline and using FileTransform task 'FileTransform@1' to update the appsettings.json as per the environment. I'm writing the variable in the yaml like below.

`"api:connection" : "xyz"`

But it's not working. So how we can update the Key which contains colon in the name from variable in the yaml pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, you are using FileTransform@1 in YAML Pipeline ro replcae the value in appsettings.json.

To set the variable contains colon , you can use `''` to define the variable name.

For example: `'xxx.xxx.api:connection': value`

```
variables:
  'xxx.xxx.api:connection': value


steps:
- task: FileTransform@1
  displayName: 'File Transform: '
  inputs:
    folderPath: 'folder'
    fileType: json
    targetFiles: 'appsettings.json '
```

At the same time, you need to define the variable name according to the json structure.

For example:

json format:

```
{
  "xx": {
    "xxx": {
      "api:connection": "xx"
    }
  }
}
```

Variable name: `'xx.xxx.api:connection'`